# Dynamic Routes in NUXTJS with two levels

Tags: javascript, nuxtjs

I would like to configure a route in my app NuxtJS. It is a simple question. Here the structure of my pages :

```
pages/
--| customers/
-----| _id.vue
--| studies/
-----| _id.vue
-----| Configuration.vue
```

I have a page with this path : myapp.com/studies/3

And I would like to set a path like this : myapp.com/studies/3/configuration.

For now with this structure it is : myapp.com/studies/configuration

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive that by changing the _id.vue file into folder and create index and configuration vue file files. Just like this ...

```
 pages/
--| customers/
-----| _id.vue
--| studies/
-----| _id/
--------| index.vue
--------| configuration.vue
```

now if you access

1. `yourapp.com/studies/3` you will get the index.vue page
2. `yourapp.com/studies/3/configuration` you will get the configuration.vue page

ask me if it is not clear for you.